# remove lines from a list that contain a duplicate zeroth element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to identify duplicate elements in a list of lines that has been split into four elements per line. I then need to keep the line with the original element and remove all lines containing the duplicate element.

For example:

```
123, jon, doe, $50
123, bob, smith, $25
456, jane, jones, $60
```

The desired output should be:

```
warning! duplicate: 123
```

and the list should then be read like this:

```
123, jon, doe, $50
456, jane, jones, $60
```

The list is very long, and so far I have tried looping through, but all I can seem to do is print out the zeroth element. I don't know how to identify and remove the lines containing a duplicate element from the list.

My guess is that the code should come before the last line, so that after the original list has been cleared of duplicates, what remains will be appended. 
If someone can help me with this I would appreciate it. This is my first question and I have tried my best to abide by all stated policies. I'm using Python 3. Thank you.

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, account_num, first_name, last_name, decimal_val):
        self.account_num = account_num
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.decimal_val = float(decimal_val)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.account_num+", "+ self.last_name+", "+self.first_name+", "+str(self.decimal_val))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.account_num == other.account_num:
            print("Warning! Account number already exists:"+self.account_num)



from BankAccount import *
total, count, average = 0, 0, 0
customer_money = [] # for a different part that is working

with open("accounts.csv", "r") as file: #original file
    contents = file.readlines() 
    customers = []
    for i in range(1,len(contents)):
        line = contents[i].split(",") #splits each line into four elements
        customers.append(BankAccount(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary here, since you want the id number to be unique, and to be able to fail if it's repeated.

Also you don't need to generate a list from `readlines()`, or use `range` to iterate over that list - you can loop on the `file` object directly. So something like:

```
customers = {}
with open("accounts.csv", "r") as file: #original file
    for i in file:
        i = i.strip()
        line = i.split(",")
        if not line[0] in customers:
            customers[line[0]] = BankAccount(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3])
        else:
            print("Duplicate!", line)
```

You can then use `customers.values()` if you just need a list of `BankAccount` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *almost* there. First, your `__eq__` method needs to be a bit different: don't try to print anything there, just indicate whether or not the two objects should be considered duplicates. That looks like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.account_id == other.account_id
```

Then you can take advantage of the `in` operator to filter your duplicates. Here's an example:

```
one = BankAccount(123, 'John', 'Doe', 39.5)
customers = [one]
two = BankAccount(123, 'Fred', 'Smith', 96.2)
assert(two in customers) # This is true
```

The last step is to add a check to your for loop before adding a new customer to your list:

```
customers = []
for i in range(1,len(contents)):
    line = contents[i].split(",") #splits each line into four elements
    account = BankAccount(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3])
    if account in customers:
        print("Duplicate account: {}".format(account.id))
    else:
        customers.append(account)
```

Note that there are plenty of other ways to achieve your goal, and some of them are probably more efficient, but I wanted to show you a solution that was very close to what you already had.

One more note: your `__str__` method doesn't quite work either - you need to change `self.account_id` to `str(self.account_id)`. Once you do that you can change the "Duplicate account" message above to `print("Duplicate account: {}".format(account))` so you get more information.